# How to separate settings for each user with Android's multi-user?

Tags: sony-xperia, multi-user

I had to use one android device for a while with multiple people, so I adopted the multi-user function. This seems to work at first because it separates video and audio files for each user.

However, changes to some settings (private DNS settings) also affect other users' settings. For this reason, it takes time and effort to correct these settings by yourself each time the user is switched.

How can I avoid such configuration interference? I'm using Xperia 10 II.